# How to delete a row using a view based on the data contains table?

Tags: mysql, view, constraints

I have now 2 tables, already defined,
The first is called `wrote` the seconds is `publication`

In publication I have 2 fields:

```
title1, title2
```

In wrote I have 3 fields:

```
Serial number, title1, title2
```

The second table foreign keys `title1,title2` is constraint to the first table primary key (both fields).
Now, I want to receive some data from the second table (`title1,title2`), and based on these rows, delete rows from the first table, I'm using views in order to retrieve and 'save' this info.

I successfully receives the data, but whenever I try to delete I get an error saying i fail a constraint, so I have to delete the row from 'wrote' before I can delete from `publication`, but then whenever I get to the deletion of the rows from `publication` the query returns empty (since it's based on deleted info)

Is there a way I can create like a 'temp table' which is not 'view' and the data in it will be saved even if I will delete the info from the table I used to query?

Here is the full query: (without creating a new table like i mentioned in the comment)

```
create or replace view WritersPerPub as
select wrote.ven_title as v2, wrote.pub_title as p2, count(pub_title) as NumOfWriters
from wrote
group by pub_title,ven_title;

create or replace view NathanWrote as
select publication.ven_title as v1 , publication.pub_title as p1
from publication,wrote
where wrote.ven_title = publication.ven_title AND
      wrote.pub_title = publication.pub_title AND
      wrote.serial_number = (   select serial_number
                                from researcher as r
                                where r.firstname = 'Nathan' AND r.surname = 'Keller');

create or replace view WrittenOnlyByNathan as
select NathanWrote.v1, NathanWrote.p1
from WritersPerPub, NathanWrote
where WritersPerPub.p2 = NathanWrote.p1 AND
      WritersPerPub.v2 = NathanWrote.v1 AND
      WritersPerPub.NumOfWriters = 1;

# Delete Nathan Keller from 'Wrote' table
delete from wrote
where serial_number = (select r.serial_number as rf1
                        from  researcher as r
                        where r.firstname = 'Nathan' AND r.surname = 'Keller');

delete from publication USING publication INNER JOIN WrittenOnlyByNathan 
where publication.pub_title = WrittenOnlyByNathan.p1 AND
  publication.ven_title = WrittenOnlyByNathan.v1;
```

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: Please show the outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE publication;`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE wrote;` and `SHOW CREATE VIEW your_view`.

Comment: in which point ? BTW, for now i created a new table , copied all the data to it, deleted the rows from the first table and then used the new created table to find the requested data for deletion... it works, but i believe there should be a better solution.